# @scope - spring - setting scope "prototype" using annotations, behaves like singleton. Where am i going wrong?

Tags: java, spring, scope, annotations

When i try to use @scope("prototype") over a class, I see it behaves similar to "singleton" I am not sure where I am wrong. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Employee class - setting scope - prototype

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope; 
@Scope("prototype")
public class Employee {

    private String emp_name;
    public String getEmp_name() {
        return emp_name;
    }

    public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
        this.emp_name = emp_name;
    }
}
```

Department class- setting scope - singleton

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
@Scope("singleton")
public class Department {
private String dep_name;

public String getDep_name() {
    return dep_name;
}
public void setDep_name(String dep_name) {
    this.dep_name = dep_name;
}
```

}

Beans.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/> 

 <!-- Scope Annotations -->
     <bean id="dep_scope" class="com.scope.annotation.Department" >
     </bean>
    <bean id="emp_scope" class="com.scope.annotation.Employee" >
     </bean>
```

Main App

```
public class MainApp {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

          Employee emp = (Employee) context.getBean("emp_scope");
          emp.setEmp_name("Saro");
          System.out.println("first"+emp.getEmp_name());

          Employee emp2 = (Employee) context.getBean("emp_scope");
          System.out.println("second"+emp2.getEmp_name());

          Department dep = (Department) context.getBean("dep_scope");
          dep.setDep_name("Maths");
          System.out.println("first"+dep.getDep_name());

          Department dep2 = (Department) context.getBean("dep_scope");
          System.out.println("second"+dep2.getDep_name());
       }
    }
```

Output :

firstSaro
secondSaro
firstMaths
secondMaths

```
I expected secondnull instead of secondSaro
```

Comment: Where you have the Annotation-scan directive?

Comment: Just try to define scope in beans.xml file in bean tag.... you are using both annotation and xml ... just use either.... it may help

Comment: @Jens I have used the <context:component-scan base-package="com"/> 
in my beans.xml, missed pasting the same here, edited my post now. Please help on it.

Comment: @Nirav Chhatrola Using xml configurations works fine, I am learning to use annotations for the same. Please could you suggest if any modifications are required.

Comment: @Sarronya remove the XML configuration adn add `@Service` to the classes and try again

Comment: Jens - @Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class Employee {
 ..} This does nt help me either. The behavior is similar to that of singletons

Answer (score 1):

Just try to define scope in beans.xml file in bean tag.... you are using both annotation and xml ... just use either..

Or you can try to define bean using annotation ... 
for that you can use **@Bean** annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

   @Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE) 
   public TestBean testBean(){
      return new TestBean();
   }
}
```

And In your main logic you can use bellow code

```
TestBean testBean = ctx.getBean(TestBean.class);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, how to apply the scope here using annotations on the bean, say testBean. As well how do i read the same from my main logic?

Comment: I am unable to do the same, please find the compilation error. Multiple markers at this line
 - The attribute scope is undefined for the annotation 
  type Bean
 - DefaultScopes cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Should I add any additional jars, apart from my spring3 Jars?

Comment: My code with compilation errors looks like...@Configuration
public class Test {

 @Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE) 
 public Employee empBean(){
       return new Employee();
    }
}

Comment: Multiple markers at this line - The attribute scope is undefined for the annotation type Bean - DefaultScopes cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 1):

It behaves as a singleton because this is the ways it is defined in the your xml conf. Default scope is singleton, prototype should be declares like follows

```
<bean id="dep_scope" class="com.scope.annotation.Department" scope="prototype">
 </bean>
```

If you want to use annotations, javadoc states that `@Scope` should be used in conjunction with `@Component`, like this

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Employee {
    //...
}

public class ExampleUsingEmployee {    
    @Inject
    private Employee enployee; //will be automatically injected by spring    
    // ... do other stuff
}
```

You should avoid (if possible) using both xml and annotations.

Comment: @ noscreenname - I tried the same, It did nt help me. Sorry !

Comment: try removing your xml config

Comment: If I remove my bean configs from xml, I am not sure on how to access these beans, from my main logic. Name of the beans ?

Comment: Use `@Autowire`, `@Inject` or `@Resource` annotation

Comment: Please could you provide a sample code for use on say Employee Bean?

Comment: I understand my scope (annotations) are overriden with the scope (xml )configurations, but how should I go abt if I am using only annotations ?

Comment: I recommend you to read the documentation on spring for more details http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring/3844/applicationcontext-configuration#t=20160803141542019499

Answer (score 0):

You have put

```
context:component-scan base-package="com"
```

which will try to instantiate beans if they are annotated with @Component or the other bean annotations like @Service, etc. But this does not make spring process the other annotations configuration.

if you want to process the other spring annotations you must register

```
context:annotation-config> .
```

too in order to ask spring to look for the annotations in the defined beans.

in summary

**context:component-scan** : will instantiate beans within the package if they are annotated with suitable annotation

**context:annotation-config** : will process the annotations in the configured beans irrespective of whether they are defined via annotations or xml.